# Font Rendering different in IE on server

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, fonts, telerik, font-size

Using Telerik Radgrid in asp.net, when I run my website on my local machine, the fonts look the same in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

[image: Local Machine]

When I promote it to the server, Chrome and Firefox look the same, but the font in IE is bigger.

[image: Server]

I installed the font on the server (Arial Narrow).  I'm stumped why IE is treating this differently, but FF and Chrome process it correctly.

Comment: Sorry hard to tell from your description - Are you logging into the server and visiting the site locally?  Or are you deploying to the server, and then visiting from a client machine's browser?

Comment: Deploying to the server, then visiting from client machine's browser.

Comment: You might try deleting all the files on the server before deploying.  Its possible you have some leftover css files from previous deployments.

Comment: Tried that and it did not work.  Any other suggestions to try?